# HttpClient.GetAsync( ) & CloudBlobBlock.UploadFromStreamAsync( ) - how is this executed?

Tags: .net, async-await, azure-blob-storage, dotnet-httpclient

I need to download a file from one place, and upload it to a azure blob. I also need to return the size of the blob when it's done:

```
public async Task<Stream> Download(string url)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
        return await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
   }
}

public async Task<long> Upload(Stream stream, string filename) 
{
   var container = GetBlobContainer(..);
   var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

   await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
   blob.FetchAttributes();

   return blob.Properties.Length;
}

public async Task<long> Action()
{
   var stream = await Download("https://.....");
   var size = await Upload(stream, "newfile.dat");

   return size;
}
```

**Questions**

- Will the `Upload` method be called before the complete stream is downloaded into memory?
- Will `Upload` start uploading bytes to azure as soon as the `HttpClient` starts to receive bytes?
- If not - is it possible to make it do so?

**Bonus:**

- How many different contexts will be generated? Should `.ConfigureAwait(false)` be used to limit context switches?
- Is `blob.FetchAttributes()` the right way of getting the size of the blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the Upload method be called before the complete stream is downloaded into memory?

No, so by default HttpClient will download the entire response into memory, and *then* give you the stream.  See: [`HttpClient.SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193601(v=vs.118).aspx).  The overload you're using specifies the [`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption(v=vs.118).aspx).  But worse yet, your code won't work, you're disposing of the `HttpClient` before you use the stream, which should cause the stream to be closed.

> Will Upload start uploading bytes to azure as soon as the HttpClient starts to receive bytes?

Again, no, see previous answer.

> If not - is it possible to make it do so?

Yes, use the `SendAsync` overload I listed earlier and set the appropriate `HttpCompletionOption`, oh, and fix that disposal issue I mentioned. :)

> How many different contexts will be generated? Should .ConfigureAwait(false) be used to limit context switches?

Not sure what you mean by "conetxts", I assume execution contexts?  That's hard to say without seeing more of your code.  But I would advise using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` unless there's some UI involved.

> Is blob.FetchAttributes() the right way of getting the size of the blob?

Personally, I would use the content length from the client's response headers myself.  But based on the MSDN documentation, that looks right.

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed through [this blog post](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/streaming-with-newnet-httpclient-and-httpcompletionoption-responseheadersread) earlier and totally missed the point, I guess...

For the disposal issue - do you have an suggestion to how this can be solved? Just remove the `using` statement all together and let the GC take care of it? Or an explicit dispose after the await? Or?
There's no UI involved. It's inside a web api controller method.

Comment: For the disposal, I would write a class that handles this code for you, and make _that_ class implement `IDisposable`, then dispose your client (and other things) in that class' dispose method.

Comment: [It looks like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551757(v=vs.118).aspx) `GetAsync( )` can take a `HttpCompletionOption`. Is it still necessary to use `SendAsync( )`?

Comment: @Vegar Nope, not as far as I know (I used SendAsync when I had a similar project because it fit my need, I didn't know which method I was going to need), as long as you can provide the proper `HttpCompletionOption` you should be ok.

Comment: I'm not able to make this work. The code just exits after client.GetAsync( ). No errors or anything. Just 'poof'...

Comment: Safe to assume you were `await`ing it?

Comment: No.. wait - I forgot to make the controller action async and await the download/upload thing...

Comment: A last question : is there a way of 'knowing' that it works? Seeing that one starts to upload before the other is finished?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand that question, know that the upload works or the download completed?  Wouldn't you know based on the fact that the proper content is in your blob?

Comment: 'it works' -> it download/upload chunks instead of downloading everything and then upload.

Comment: Not really, the closest you could come to proving it is to use a very large file and watch your memory consumption; clearly if it were downloading the entire response on a 1GB file you're going to see that reflected in your memory usage